# JPA executeUpdate always returns 1

Tags: java, jpa

I'm having an issue here where the executeUpdate command always returns value 1 even though there's no record to be updated.

First I retrieve several records, do a bit of calculation, and then update the status of some of the retrieved records.

The JPA update code:

```
private int executeUpdateStatusToSuccess(Long id, Query updateQuery) {
    updateQuery.setParameter(1, getSysdateFromDB());
    updateQuery.setParameter(2, id);
    int cnt = updateQuery.executeUpdate();
    return cnt; // always return 1
}
```

The update query:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT_PARAM SET STATUS = 2, DATA_TIMESTAMP=? WHERE ID = ? AND STATUS=-1
```

Note that **STATUS** column is practically never valued < 0. I'm purposely adding this condition here just to show that even though it shouldn't have updated any record, the executeUpdate() still returns the value 1.

As an additional note, there is no update process anywhere between the data retrieval and the update. It's all done within my local environment.

Any advice if I'm possibly missing anything here? Or if there's some configuration parameter that I need to checK?

EDIT:
For the JPA I'm using EclipseLink.
For the database I'm using Oracle 10g with driver ojdbc5.jar.

Comment: Have you checked the backend data prior to this? If its returning 1 then that should mean one row has been updated

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the data is not updated.

Comment: As a test - can you try a findByID prior to update to check values? It might be the database has a cascade update on this field that your not aware of

Comment: what is the result of this query if you run it directly in database not through java?

Comment: I can confirm that there is no update taking place in the database. Whether I query the data again via the application or back-end after the update process it shows the same old values. Unless it's a bug or I'm missing something obvious I don't know why the JPA is returning 1 here.
@farrellmr, I've just tried the findByID prior to checking the values: it's still the same value. So there is no unexpected update.
bhdrkn, it updates 0 record.

Comment: Which persistence provider you're using? Hibernate, OpenJPA, EclipseLink? Also which database and which database driver version?

Comment: Id enable full logging on your ORM to see whats going on

Comment: and the SQL is? and log entries around that are?

Comment: Sami, I'm using EclipseLink. For the database I'm using Oracle 10g with ojdbc5.jar.
Farrelmr, that's a good suggestion! Will give it a try next Monday.
@Neil, do you mean the Select query's SQL? For the logs are you referring to the ORM logs? I'll check it out once I'm back in the office next Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have to look into the EclipseLink JPA source code. So the system actually executes this line

```
return Integer.valueOf(1);
```

from the codes inside `basicExecuteCall` method of `DatabaseAccessor` class below:

```
if (isInBatchWritingMode(session)) {
    // if there is nothing returned and we are not using optimistic locking then batch
    //if it is a StoredProcedure with in/out or out parameters then do not batch
    //logic may be weird but we must not batch if we are not using JDBC batchwriting and we have parameters
    // we may want to refactor this some day
    if (dbCall.isNothingReturned() && (!dbCall.hasOptimisticLock() || getPlatform().canBatchWriteWithOptimisticLocking(dbCall) ) 
        && (!dbCall.shouldBuildOutputRow()) && (getPlatform().usesJDBCBatchWriting() || (!dbCall.hasParameters())) && (!dbCall.isLOBLocatorNeeded())) {
        // this will handle executing batched statements, or switching mechanisms if required
        getActiveBatchWritingMechanism().appendCall(session, dbCall);
        //bug 4241441: passing 1 back to avoid optimistic lock exceptions since there   
        // is no way to know if it succeeded on the DB at this point.
        return Integer.valueOf(1);
    } else {
        getActiveBatchWritingMechanism().executeBatchedStatements(session);
    }
}
```

One easy hack will be by not using the batch. I've tried turning it off in persistence.xml and the update returns the expected value, which is 0.

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="none" />
```

I'm expecting better solution but this one will do for now in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question and answer are pretty old but since I stumbled upon this same problem recently and figured out a solution for my use-case (keep batch-writing enabled and still get the updated rows count for some queries), I figured my solution might be helpful to somebody else in the future.

Basically, you can use a query hint to signal that a specific query does not support batch execution. The code to do this is something like this:

```java
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.HintValues;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class EclipseLinkUtils {
  public static void disableBatchWriting(Query query) {
       query.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH_WRITING, HintValues.FALSE);
  }
}
```